# Ionic 2: Split screen into two individual parts

Tags: ionic2

I would like to create a page that would be divided into two (upper and lower) and I want to display items (for simplicity - list entries) on both parts and every time item will be clicked I want it to move to the other part of the screen.
Thinking about the future I want that both parts would be scrollable.

Is there a way to achieve such behaviour using ionic components?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have not tested the following code but I think this would work and answers your need.

In your page controller (for instance `HomePage`) :

```
export class HomePage {
    top_item_array = ["Item A", "Item B", "Item C"]
    bottom_item_array = ["Item D", "Item E", "Item F"]

    constructor(){
    }

    move_from_top_to_bottom(idx){
      this.bottom_item_array.push(this.top_item_array[idx])
      this.top_item_array.splice(idx, 1)
    }

    move_from_bottom_to_top(idx){
      this.top_item_array.push(this.bottom_item_array[idx])
      this.bottom_item_array.splice(idx, 1)
    }
}
```

And in the `<ion-content>` of your template :

```
<ion-scroll scrollX="true" scrollY="true" style="height: 100px;">
    <h2>Top</h2>
    <ion-list>
        <ion-item *ngFor="let item of top_item_array; let idx = index" (tap)="move_from_top_to_bottom(idx)">
            {{item}}
        </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
</ion-scroll>
<ion-scroll scrollX="true" scrollY="true" style="height: 100px;">
    <h2>Bottom</h2>
    <ion-list>
        <ion-item *ngFor="let item of bottom_item_array; let idx = index" (tap)="move_from_bottom_to_top(idx)">
            {{item}}
        </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
</ion-scroll>
```

Does it helps?

Comment: Perfect! `style="height: 100px;"` did the trick for me. Thanks.

Comment: Glad this helped ;) !