# ionic2: Limit a list to show only X items at time and add a scroll bar

Tags: ionic2

I have an array with many items in it and I want to display it using `<ion-list>` but the thing is that I don't want the list to cover all my page but limit it to let's say 50% of the page. So basically I want it to show about 5 items at a time and have a scroll bar just for the list view. How do I approach this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you want to use an `<ion-scroll>` (documentation [here](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/nightly/api/components/scroll/Scroll/)) like I suggest in my answer to your other question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40809494/ionic-2-split-screen-into-two-individual-parts).